# Mapping a list to a dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have this class:

```
class ClassFrom
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

I want to map it into this, with the `Id` property becoming the dictionary's key:

```
class ClassTo
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}

Dictionary<int, ClassTo> toDict
    = mapper.Map<List<ClassFrom>, Dictionary<int, ClassTo>>(fromList);
```

Is there a recommended way to accomplish this?

The best way I've found to do this using Automapper has a slight code smell to me. I am essentially double-mapping the object, first to `ClassTo` and then to `KeyValuePair` through its constructor:

```
var cfg = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
{
    c.CreateMap<ClassFrom, ClassTo>();

    c.CreateMap<ClassFrom, KeyValuePair<int, ClassTo>>()
        .ForCtorParam("key", paramOptions => paramOptions.MapFrom(from => from.Id))
        .ForCtorParam("value", paramOptions => paramOptions.MapFrom(from => from));
});

IMapper mapper = new AutoMapper.Mapper(cfg);

List<ClassFrom> fromList = new List<ClassFrom>
{
    new ClassFrom { Id = 1, Foo = "foo1", Bar = "Bar1" },
    new ClassFrom { Id = 2, Foo = "foo2", Bar = "Bar2" }
};

Dictionary<int, ClassTo> toDict
    = mapper.Map<List<ClassFrom>, Dictionary<int, ClassTo>>(fromList);
```

Comment: why use automapper for this? why not just: `var toDict = fromList.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => new ClassTo { Foo = x.Foo, Bar = x.Bar });`

Comment: That's not "mapping", it's a transformation. AM is not the right tool.

Comment: @MarcGravell For the trivial sample I agree with you, but I'd hope it's obvious that this is merely a sample. Lets assume that Automapper is appropriate here.

Comment: @CoryNelson we cant safely assume that its appropriate when you ask the question. Are you getting any errors or is it just not working for you

Comment: I agree with @CoryNelson that this is valid. I can easily imagine that this is a small fraction of a larger system with many other types where, in one domain, type `A` has a `List<T>` property and, in another domain, type `B` has a `Dictionary<string, T>` property. When attempting to `.Map<A, B>(source)`, this `MapperConfiguration` is perfectly relevant.

Answer (score 4):

You can use *ConstructUsing* instead of *ForCtorParam*. If you change the mapper configuration like below, it will work correctly.

```
var cfg = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
        {
            c.CreateMap<ClassFrom, ClassTo>();

            c.CreateMap<ClassFrom, KeyValuePair<int, ClassTo>>()
                .ConstructUsing(x => new KeyValuePair<int, ClassTo>(x.Id, new ClassTo { Bar = x.Bar, Foo = x.Foo }));
        });
```

Comment: Yes, but you don't need the first map anymore. And ConvertUsing fits better because nothing else get mapped after ConstructUsing.

Comment: Are you sure not to mapped after ConstructUsing? I tried to mapped after ConstructUsing then I don't get any exception. Can you give more details?

Comment: This is only practical if the manual conversion from `ClassFrom` to `ClassTo` is trivial. Consider more elaborate objects that have properties that need to be converted as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the [ToDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277(v=vs.110).aspx) extension method in the System.Linq namespace.

```
//using System.Linq;
var toDict = fromList.ToDictionary
(
    //Define key
    element => element.Id,   

    //Define value
    element => new ClassTo { Foo = element.Foo, Bar = element.Bar } 
);
```